# The following error was received while trying to encrypt your password: Artifactory response: 403 Forbidden

Tags: artifactory, artifact, jfrog-cli

I am getting the below error when running the Jenkins Job but the Test connection was successful when I tested after configured in Jenkins Global configuration. Could someone please help me out on this issue?

```
jfrog c add artifactory-server --artifactory-url=https://test-artifactory.company.com/artifactory --user=**** --password=****
```

> The following error was received while trying to encrypt your password:
> Artifactory response: 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below syntax and check if it works? `=` is not required in the parameter.

**Syntax:**

```
jfrog config add <named_server_config> --artifactory-url $ARTIFACTORY_URL --user $ARTIFACTORY_USER --apikey $ARTIFACTORY_APIKEY --interactive=false
```

**Example:**

```
jfrog config add arti-server --artifactory-url http://IP:PORT/artifactory --user **** --password **** --interactive=false
```

**or**

```
jfrog c add arti-server --artifactory-url http://IP:PORT/artifactory --user **** --password **** --interactive=false
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Sorry, that was my mistake when posting. I am using without '-' only. Going to correct the original post.

Comment: @Ash Updated my answer, Can you try with the updated syntax?